# How to make small changes for console output without repeating all unchanged values

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to create a text game in C# with console interface

The basic process goes like this:

1. Take user input.
2. Manipulate the map (2d array) based on the user input.
3. Print out the map.
4. Repeat.

The game works fine, but my problem is that it flickers whenever you try to move the character because it has to go through an entire nested for loop to print out the map each time.

Can I change still different parts of the console output to avoid flickers?

My current actual code for display map at every step:

```
Console.Clear();
for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 58; x++)
    {
        // map is an array with current state for each cell on the map
        Console.Write(map[y, x]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: We are not going to go elsewhere to review your code. If you have a question about your code, [edit] your post, include the **relevant portions** of it here, and ask a specific question related to that code. For more info, see [ask]. Having all of the content off-site means that if that off-site location is unavailable for some reason (deleted, off-line, moved, etc.), your question has zero useful content for future users here.

Comment: If you are going to use an external source for your code (which you shouldn't), at the very least use a source that is actually made for hosting code. Google Docs is a terrible place to post your code for review. Use something like pastebin or dotnetfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. This is my first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reprint all the map for each cycle. The better way is to use [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method and rewrite just modified symbols:

```
foreach(var changedSymbol in changes)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(changedSymbol.Row, changedSymbol.Column)
    Console.Write(changedSymbol.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, Works great!