# How to update console status line without repeating output?

Tags: go, console

I have an app which processes lots of jobs and occasionally outputs using `fmt.Println()`.

Currently, it outputs `Job x/total` after each job completes. For example:

```
Some output
Again output
Job 5/300
Another output
Job 6/300
```

The problem is this is repeated, whereas I'm trying to get the `Job` line to stay fixed.

I would like to output a kind of status line which can be updated but without repeating. For example

```
Some output
More output <-- these can repeat from Println()
Job 23/200 <-- this should remain fixed but be updatable
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333257/how-to-make-small-changes-for-console-output-without-repeating-all-unchanged-val) but it's for C#

Is this possible in Go?

Comment: You can do it the exact same way you would typing, backspace over the characters and write new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep updating a message by using ANSI escape codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

For example:

```
func main() {
    const total = 5
    completed := 0
    saveCursorPosition := "\033[s"
    clearLine := "\033[u\033[K"

    go func() {
        jobTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
        for {
            <-jobTicker.C
            completedJobs++
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second / 2)
    fmt.Print(saveCursorPosition)
    for {
        if completed == total {
            fmt.Println("\nAll jobs were completed")
            break
        }
        <-ticker.C
        fmt.Print(clearLine)
        fmt.Printf("Job %d/%d", completed, total)
    }
}
```

But since it's always returning to the same cursor position, other prints will overwrite the `Job x/y` message.

And you can't change the cursor position and then go back to the older one, so you would have to print the jobs log and the other outputs every time a job is completed.